# Understanding Working Precision - two example equations

Tags: numerics, special-functions, machine-precision, precision-and-accuracy

I am trying to understand how  `WorkingPrecision` works, and in general how very small/large numbers are to be handled.
Let me preface I probably do not have sufficient theoretical knowledge on floating\arbitrary precision numbers: please do not hesitate to suggest a good book to understand the topic from the applications point of view.

Anyhow, I am dealing with  the complete elliptic integral of the first kind, `EllipticK`, which I believe displays a logarithmic divergence for $k \to 1$.

If I attempt

```
     rooteK2[a_] := 
      NSolve[{EllipticK[k] == a, 0 <= k <= 1}, k, WorkingPrecision -> 200]
```

I get no solutions.

Yet If I try

```
    rootlog[a_] := NSolve[Log[x] == -a, x, WorkingPrecision -> 100]
```

I get

```
  rootlog[1000]
  {{x -> 1.1354838653147360985409388750662484019574316100903188426715526\
  5915730430241273915784077651790431*10^-4343}}
```

which I find surprising, as I believe the divergence is similar (for $x \to 1$ and $x \to 0$ in the elliptic integral and logarithmic function respectively).

Further, If I try

```
EllipticK[0.9999999999999999]
```

I obtain

```
  19.7547
```

but one more digit

```
  EllipticK[0.99999999999999999]
```

and I get

```
  ComplexInfinity
```

On the other hand

```
  Log[1 - 0.99999999999999999]
```

returns

```
Indeterminate
```

and not Infinity. Further, in the example above with `NSolve`, numbers such $10^-4343$ were seemingly handled, certainly smaller than $1 - 0.99999999999999999$.

I would be really interested to understand the difference and learn more abo about accuracy, thanks a lot, much appreciated.

**EDIT** Following Bob Hanlon's comments below, I would like to clarify I am using version 11.2.
If I issue e.g.

```
EllipticK[0.9999999999999999999`100]
```

I do get an answer $\approx 23.26086 \dots$.

Yet, if I try to back-calculate the argument of `EllipticK` used just above via `` rooteK2[23.26086`100] `` (as defined at the beginning of the post)
I get no answer (differently from version 12.2).

Comment: `EllipticK[0.99999999999999999]` The argument is a machine number so the calculation is done with machine precision. Specify a precision to use arbitrary-precision. `EllipticK[0.99999999999999999\`100]` or `EllipticK[SetPrecision[1-10^-17, 100]]` or `N[EllipticK[1-10^-17], 100]`

Comment: @BobHanlon, that is understood, thanks a lot. Yet, when I look for the root with ````rooteK2[a_] := 
 NSolve[{EllipticK[k] == a, 0 <= k <= 1}, k, WorkingPrecision -> 200] ```` still do not get a result for ````rooteK2[50] ````  nor  ````rooteK2[50.`300] ````, could you please clarify further,  thanks for the patience

Comment: Using your suggestion, I can calculate values for arguments of the elliptic functions extremely close to 1. I would also expect NSolve to be able to back-calculate those.

Comment: `rooteK2[50.\`200]` works for me with version 12.1. What version are you using?

Comment: @BobHanlon, I am using 11.2

Comment: Edit your question to include your version number. Perhaps someone with access to that version can help.

Comment: In your edit you used rootK2 with a machine number input so you are not using arbitrary-precision.

Comment: A common ref for FP is [Goldberg](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/103162.103163); but almost any numerical analysis textbook since the 1990s would probably have a (shorter) chapter on FP.  More extensive treatments are [Higham](https://doi-org.proxy.library.emory.edu/10.1137/1.9780898718027) (on application to numerical analysis) and [Overton](https://doi-org.proxy.library.emory.edu/10.1137/1.9780898718072) (on the IEEE 754 standard). Not sure either of those are what you're looking for.  "Arbitrary precision" is a Wolfram thing (see documentation). It's like FP but somewhat different.

Comment: @MichaelE2, thanks a lot, the first reference looks an excellent starting point.